What does it mean to be $(M, s)$-homogeneous?
I'm trying to get a handle on the Assouad dimension and Wikipedia says that for a metric space $(X, \zeta)$,

The Assouad dimension of $X$, $d_A(X)$, is the infimum of all $s$ such that $(X, \zeta)$ is $(M, s)$-homogenous for some $M \geq 1$.

What does it mean to be $(M, s)$-homogenous? Is there a general notion of homogeneity? Whenever I search for a definition online, I see people referring to it but never really defining it.

Have you read the book in the reference? It explains in Definition 9.1.

@LidingYao thanks. i didn't realize it would give me that link.

There are a couple of notions of homogeneity which show up in the literature, depending on whether you are working in a purely metric setting, or in a metric space which already carries a measure (unlike the Hausdorff dimension, the Assouad dimension does not "come from" a measure, but it has the potential to "play nice" with Radon measures, so it is not entirely inappropriate to give a definition in terms of measures).
In a purely metric setting, the usual definition is something like

Definition:  Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and suppose that $A \subseteq X$.  For any $0< \rho < r$, let $\mathcal{N}_A(r,\rho)$ denote the number of balls of radius $\rho$ required to cover any ball of radius $r$ which is contained in $A$.  The set $A$ is $(M,s)$-homogenous (with $M\ge 1$ and $s \ge 0$) if
$$ \mathcal{N}_{A}(r,\rho) \le K \left( \frac{r}{\rho} \right)^s. $$

For further discussion, see [1].  This is the definition I adopted in my masters thesis, which was advised by Eric Olson (one of the authors of the cited paper).  See also [2], which gives a similar definition.  Wikipedia also cites [3], which is a good source—John's exposition is quite clear and easy to read.
The intuition of this definition is that any ball should look roughly the same, no matter the scale:  the number of little balls required to cover a big ball should roughly correspond to the ratio of the radii of the big and little balls, and the dimension of the space.  A useful toy example is squares / cubes / hypercubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The square $[-r,r]^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is a ball of radius $r$ with respect to the metric $$d\bigl( (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \bigr) = \max\{ |x_1-x_2|, |y_1-y_2|),$$
i.e. the metric coming from the sup-norm or max-norm) can always be covered by $(r/\rho+1)^2$ (or fewer) squares of side length $2\rho$ (these are balls of radius $\rho$ in the appropriate metric).  You can see this by dividing each side of the big square into segments of length $\rho$ (with possibly a little left over at the end), and then noting each side will be divided into at most $r/\rho+1$ pieces—hence it takes $(r/\rho+1)^2$ little squares to cover the big square (at most).  Thus
$$ \mathcal{N}_{A}(r,\rho) \le \left( \frac{r}{\rho} + 1\right)^2
= \left( \frac{r}{\rho} \right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{r}{\rho}\right) + 1. $$
By assumption $r > \rho$, so $r/\rho > 1$.  This gives the (somewhat loose, but still correct) bound
$$ \left( \frac{r}{\rho} \right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{r}{\rho}\right) + 1
< \left( \frac{r}{\rho} \right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{r}{\rho}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{r}{\rho} \right)^2
= 5\left( \frac{r}{\rho} \right)^2.
$$
Therefore $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $(5,2)$-homogeneous (with respect to the metric induced by the max-norm).
Hopefully, it is not too hard to see that if a space is $(M,s)$-homogeneous, then it is also $(M',s')$-homogeneous for any $M' \ge M$ and $s' \ge s$.  In particular, if $X$ is $(M,s)$-homogeneous for some $M \ge 1$ and $s \ge 0$, then it will also be $(M,s')$-homogeneous for any $s' > s$, which further implies that there is an infimal value $\sigma$ such that $X$ is $(M,s)$-homogeneous for some $M$ and all $s \ge \sigma$.  This infimal value is the Assouad dimension of the space.
This should be roughly the intuition that we have from Euclidean spaces and our "usual" notion of dimension:  if you scale a line by a factor of $k$, the length of the line scales by a factor of $k$; but if you scale a cube by a factor of $k$, the volume of the cube scales by a factor of $k^3$.  The dimension of a space is the exponent which correctly captures this scaling behaviour.  The Assouad dimension extends this idea to arbitrary metric spaces.
Note, however, that this intuition relies on the idea of there being a measure present on the space, e.g. an area or volume, and the Assouad dimension does not rely on any such notion.  Thus the number of little balls used to cover a big ball becomes the best proxy (this is, essentially, the intuition behind the definition of Hausdorff measure and Hausdorff dimension).  If a given space already carries a measure, there is another notion of Assouad dimension which may be relevant:

Definition:  Let $(X,d,\mu)$ be a space with metric $d$ and Radon measure $\mu$, and let $A \subseteq X$.  The measure $\mu$ is $(M,s)$-homogeneous on $A$ if for any $0<\rho<r$, $x\in A$, and $\xi \in B(x,r)$, the inequality
$$ \frac{\mu(B(x,r)}{r^s} \le M \frac{\mu(B(\xi,\rho))}{\rho^s}. $$

To the best of my knowledge, this specific construction was first introduced by [3], but they do not give a name to the condition.  In my PhD thesis, I refer to a set as $s$-homogeneous if the above condition holds for some $M>0$, though I do not think that this is a standard idea anywhere.

[1] Olson, Eric J.; Robinson, James C., Almost bi-Lipschitz embeddings and almost homogeneous sets, Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 362, No. 1, 145-168 (2010). ZBL1197.54045.
[2] Robinson, James C., Dimensions, embeddings, and attractors, Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics 186. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-0-521-89805-8/hbk). xii, 205 p. (2011). ZBL1222.37004.
[3] Fraser, Jonathan M. Assouad Dimension and Fractal Geometry. Cambridge University Press. (2020).
[4] Lehrbäck, Juha; Tuominen, Heli, A note on the dimensions of Assouad and Aikawa, J. Math. Soc. Japan 65, No. 2, 343-356 (2013). ZBL1279.54022.

This is an amazing explanation. Thank you!

@roundsquare It is so very rare for anyone to ask questions about things I know.  Always happy to speak up when it happens. :D
